# Tableview custom cell pass the data to the next page

Tags: swift, uitableview, cell

I have been trying for days to make a custom cell button into a table view cell. I want to press the button "AddItem" and pass the data of that row that I pressed and pass data to the next screen into the label. I have looked at multiple solutions for questions similar to mine in stack view and I still can't get mine to work. Can anyone help me here? Screenshots of app are given below.

here is my code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate {

    let item = ["Apple","Orange"]
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return item.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = item[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }


    @IBOutlet var tblView: UITableView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

}
```

[first page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SNXfZ.png)

[second page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZxqQL.png)

Comment: Have you added ur `Button` to ur Cell ?

Comment: Yes i have added it to the cell. I have read in some other stackview similar questions and tutorials that i need to create a cellview class for the cell. I have also tried that but i have no luck passing the data to the next page by clicking the button.

Answer (score 0):

Add stroyboard identifier to the NexVC

[image]

Then

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

     let vc = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NextVC") as! NextVC
     vc.loadViewIfNeeded()
     vc.lbl.text = item[indexPath.row]
     self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)

}
```

---

Inside `cellForRowAt`

```
    cell.button.tag = indexPath.row

    cell.button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)

    return cell
}

@objc func buttonTapped (_ sender:UIButton) {

    print(item[sender.tag])
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But what about the additem button? I want to pass along the information of that row that I press the button to the next page.

Comment: if you need to set information according to it , you can access directly the item array for that data inside `didSelectRowAt`

Comment: But i want to pass the information by clicking the additem button not just by selecting the row.

Comment: Hi I managed to get it to work using your solution and also adding a class of for the cell. Here is my code if anyone is intrested:

class AddItemClassCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet var addBtn: UIButton!
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }
    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    }
}

Comment: @objc private func BtnClicked(sender: UIButton) {
        //let ip = tblview.indexPathForSelectedRow
       // print(ip)
        let vc = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NextVC") as! NextVC
        vc.loadViewIfNeeded()
        vc.lb.text = menu[sender.tag]
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
        }